# Out of stock mail subscription Not working

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions

I am using this extensions,

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-out-of-stock-subscription.html

After instalation click mail id, right after click subscribe, no action taken.

I am getting error :

Console Error : https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5sXO.png

Networkik Error : https://i.stack.imgur.com/bI2vQ.png

Log Error :

```
a:5:{i:0;s:39:"This product is currently out of stock.";i:1;s:1205:"#0 /home/xyz/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Cart.php(284): Mage::throwException('This product is...')
#1 /home/xyz/public_html/app/code/local/Cmsmart/AjaxCart/controllers/IndexController.php(310): Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart->addProduct('31543', Array)
#2 /home/xyz/public_html/app/code/local/Cmsmart/AjaxCart/controllers/IndexController.php(133): Cmsmart_AjaxCart_IndexController->tryaddAction(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), Array)
#3 /home/xyz/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Cmsmart_AjaxCart_IndexController->indexAction()
#4 /home/xyz/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#5 /home/xyz/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#6 /home/xyz/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#7 /home/xyz/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#8 /home/xyz/public_html/index.php(88): Mage::run('', 'store')
#9 {main}";s:3:"url";s:111:"/ajaxcart/index/index/?product=31543&related_product=&subscription_email=xyz%40gmail.com&_=1478327890211";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"english";}
```

Comment: May be there is a issue of file missing,
or any file conflict.

Comment: Could you pls suggest free notify mail for sold out products